# Can a computed field be set to anything other that VARCHAR(MAX)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a field `District` which is `VARCHAR(5)`

When I create a computed field:

```
ALTER TABLE
  Postcode
ADD
 DistrictSort1
AS
  (dbo.fn_StripCharacters(District, '^A-Z'))
PERSISTED;
```

The computed field `DistrictSort1` is added as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Is it possible to change the `NVARCHAR` to anything other than `(MAX)`?

Are there any performance issues?

Comment: So the return type of `fn_StripCharacters` is `nvarchar(max)`? Can you change the return type of the UDF, or just cast it to something else?

Comment: *"The computed field DistrictSort1 is added as NVARCHAR(MAX)"* That would mean that your function, `fn_StripCharacters` is defined to return that. The problem isn't the column, it's the function. Perhaps you should have multiple versions of `dbo.fn_StripCharacters` that return different data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer would be to `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value explicitly in your computed column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Postcode
ADD DistrictSort1 AS CONVERT(varchar(5),(dbo.fn_StripCharacters(District, '^A-Z')) PERSISTED;
```

I would, however, suggest looking at your function `fn_StripCharacters`, which is currently set up to return an `nvarchar(MAX)`. User defined functions, unlike those built into SQL Server, cannot return different data types based on their input parameter(s). As a result, whenever you reference your function, you will get an `nvarchar(MAX)` back.

As a result, sometimes it's best to have multiple similar versions of the same function. For one like this, form example, you might want 4, that return `varchar` and `nvarchar` values in non-`MAX` and `MAX` lengths.

Comment: Good answer. I am using a generic function which does return ```NVARCHAR(MAX)```. I looked in SSMS to alter the computed field type and there was nothing obvious to allow this. Using ```CAST``` is probably the way I will go for the time being but having multiple functions with different output types may be the better long-term solution.

Comment: You can't `ALTER` a computed column, @Coilover ; you have to `DROP` and re`CREATE` it.

Comment: Yeah, found that out.